# Вычисление интеграла методом Гаусса-Лежандра

Tags: c#, математика

Необходимо найти значение определённого интеграла с использованием квадратур Гаусса-Лежандра.

Это численный метод решения, имеющий высокую точность расчета (в данном примере до 6 знаков) за небольшое количество вычислений.

Теория:

[Метод Гаусса (численное интегрирование)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0_(%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

[Gauss–Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature)

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Численное_интегрирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

[image: Интеграл]

Comment: Если вы хотите поделиться чем-то полезным, то для этого есть форма самоответа - задаете вопрос по всем правилам, сами отвечаете,  через время принимаете свой ответ (може быть, кто-то ещё лучше ответит, и вам польза будет)

Comment: Данный метод я уже применил для процедурного расчета, поэтому суть и выложил. И конечно не против возможного улучшения.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы мы посмотрели корректность решения? Если да, добавьте метку `инспекция-кода` и опишите, в чем именно сомнения в представленном решении. Если нет, перенесите ответную часть поста в отдельный пост для ответа ниже. Здесь используется формат "вопрос-оствет", данный пост следует подогнать под этот формат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкладываю ответ на свой вопрос, т.е. простой пример метода для сообщества.

**Веса и значения аргумента нужно брать из этой таблицы.**
Степень полинома - это число точек в квадратуре.

Его можно использовать для нахождения длины кривой, равноудаленных точек на кривой или движения с постоянной скоростью объекта в играх.

```
using System;
    
    namespace MyGaussLegandre
    {
        class Program
        {
    
            public static double GaussLegendre(Function f, double a, double b, int n)
            {
                // Число точек в квадратуре - 2
                double[] w = { 1.0, 1.0 }; // весовые коэффициенты
                double[] x = { -0.577350269, +0.577350269 }; // значения аргумента
    
    
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    sum += 0.5 * (b - a) * w[i] * f(0.5 * (a + b) + 0.5 * (b - a) * x[i]);
                }
                return sum;
            }
    
            // Делегат
            public delegate double Function(double x);
    
            // Интегрируемая функция y = 4*x^3 
            static double f2(double x)
            {
                return 4 * Math.Pow(x, 3);
            }
    
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
                Console.WriteLine("\nResult from Gauss-Legendre method:\n");
                
                double a, b, result;
    
                // f2 - интегрируемая функция
                // a,b - пределы интегрирования
                // n - степень полинома Лежандра
    
                a = 0;
                b = Math.PI;
    
                result = GaussLegendre(f2, a, b, 2);
    
                Console.WriteLine("result = {0}", result);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Таблица весов]

Comment: Зря от инспекции отказались, здесь можно было улучшить код. Например при n > 2 метод выдаст исключение. Если же n - константа, то зачем она в аргументах? Еще переменные можно объявлять одновременно с первичным присваиванием, а не заранее, так код легче читать. Кастомный делегат соответствует уже существующему обобщенномк `Func<double, double>`, его использоание также упростило бы чтение кода. Ну и прочие мелочи.

Comment: Благодарю вас.  Это пример для решения метода. Веса и аргументы при n > K также должны меняться по известным таблицам. В моем прикладном решении я использовал как раз кастомный делегат.

Comment: Еще неплохо бы объяснить, как от формулы вы пришли к такому алгоритму. Что это за весовые коэффициенты и прочие константы в массивах. Ссылки на теорию в вопросе - хорошо, но они могут испортиться со временем, поэтому лучше всю необходимую для понимания вопроса и ответа информацию, лучше публиковать прямо в постах.

Comment: Да-да, вот я и пишу сейчас. Это расчет полинома Лежандра, т.е. готовая таблица есть. Сейчас добавлю скрин.

Comment: Окей, значит вы выложили скорее не решение по интегрированию чего угодно, а решение данной конкретной задачи из примера. Если поменяются условия задачи, код придется переписывать. Это не ошибка, но слабый задел развития решения - потенциальная проблема для тех, кто попытается применить ваш способ к решению своих задач. Просто как совет.

Comment: Попробовал посчитать от -2 до 1 `3 * x * x` (ну потому что в уме считается весьма легко), ответ почти попал, стоит еще округлять вывод. Например до 6 знаков как в примере `Console.WriteLine($"result = {result:F6}");`.

Comment: Обсуждение хорошее. Лично у меня работает сначала понимание метода, а реализацию написать и шлифануть не большая проблема. Далее идет 2 способа реализации: 1) использовать эту таблицу до 6-ти точек 2) расчет полинома.

Comment: Для меня если честно матан - давно забытое прошлое. Поэтому я вообще без понятия, что это за квадратурные точки и зачем они :) Здесь вам виднее, как лучше. Алгоритмически полином мог бы быть лучше.